# How to show a page number on every page in a PDF using voghDev/PdfViewPager library?

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-viewpager

It's been days of researching and I cannot figure out a way to do it.

Here is the link of the library on Github. [Library](https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager)

```
public class PDFViewActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout root;
    EditText etPdfUrl;
    Button btnDownload;
    PDFPagerAdapter adapter;
    String id;
    ArrayList<String> topicLink;
    File file;
    String filePath;

    PDFViewPager pdfViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_p_d_f_view);

        root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.remote_pdf_root);
        final Context ctx = this;

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("filePath");
        str = str;   // This contains the path of the PDF on my device
        Log.i("filePathInString", str);


        pdfViewPager = new PDFViewPager(ctx, str);
        pdfViewPager.setId(R.id.pdfViewPager);
        pdfViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
        
        adapter = new PDFPagerAdapter(ctx, str);
        pdfViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        
        root.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        root.addView(pdfViewPager,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ((PDFPagerAdapter) pdfViewPager.getAdapter()).close();
    }
    
}
```

The PDF renders perfectly form my device but I cannot see the page numbers, title , total pages of the PDF when the PDF is loaded.

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/remote_pdf_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".PDFViewActivity1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <es.voghdev.pdfviewpager.library.PDFViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pdfViewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

What do I do when the page is scrolled, I cannot figure out a thing , I tried a lot of methods of the PDFAdapter but I an unsuccessful :( How can I do the task ?

Comment: Do I need to add a view in pdfViewPager.addView(args..) and then set the page number on it, if anyone could execute ?

Answer (score 1):

```java
RelativeLayout remotePdfRoot = findViewById(R.id.remote_pdf_root);
    
remotePDFViewPager = new RemotePDFViewPager(this, downloadFileUrlConnection, url, listener);
remotePDFViewPager.setId(R.id.pdfViewPager);
    
//after file loading success
PDFPagerAdapter adapter = new PDFPagerAdapter(this, FileUtil.extractFileNameFromURL(url));
remotePDFViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
updateLayout();
    
private void updateLayout() {
    remotePdfRoot.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    remotePdfRoot.addView(remotePDFViewPager, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

I preview pdf this way and there will be a pagenumber.

Comment: Which line of code adds the page number ? Can you post the XML also

Comment: I have completely updated my initial post to give more clarity.

Comment: no page number is shown... but the PDF render nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer library for this and you can get the page count by

```
`vpPdf.fromAsset("sample.pdf").onError {
        Log.i(TAG, "${it.localizedMessage}")
        it.printStackTrace()
     }.onPageError { _, t ->
        t.printStackTrace()
     }.enableSwipe(true).swipeHorizontal(true).onPageChange { page, pageCount ->
     //here page count is count of page user currently is viewing.
     }.load()`
```

I had to use this lib at work and it is working perfectly fine!!
The above code is from kotlin but you can convert it to java i guess,If you are not able to convert it the kindly comment so i will help you with that too!!.

Comment: It's a great library but for me app size matters and barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer  is a very heavy library. Anyway I contacted with the developer of the library mentioned in the post and I found a way to solve the problem.

Comment: how do you solve it out.... please put the step by step or at least tutorial one. @RandyOrton  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try, in Kotlin

```
 override fun onSuccess(url: String?, destinationPath: String?) {

    adapter = PDFPagerAdapter(this, FileUtil.extractFileNameFromURL(url))
    remotePDFViewPager.adapter = adapter
    remotePDFViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrolled(
            position: Int,
            positionOffset: Float,
            positionOffsetPixels: Int
        ) {
        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {}
        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            var totalPages = remotePDFViewPager.adapter?.count
            var currentPage = remotePDFViewPager.currentItem +1
            tvCurrentPage!!.text = currentPage.toString()+" / "+ totalPages
        }
    })
```